# How to connect Spark Streaming with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils    

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["topic"], {"metadata.broker.list":"prd-kafka:9092,prd-kafka1:9092,prd-kafka:9092,"})
```

**I trying to no connect spark streaming with, to read some topic and write in hdfs.
But there is a problem, follow bellow**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.3-1.cdh5.9.3.p0.4/lib/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 152, in createDirectStream
    raise e
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o73.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
        at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:720)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**I think my connection must be similar that**

```
format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) \
    .option("kafka.batch.size", 5000) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "metadata.broker.list":"prd-kafka:9092,prd-kafka1:9092,prdkafka:9092,") \
    .option("subscribe", "topic")
```

Somebody knows how to connect spark streaming with kafka using "SCHA-SHA-256" mechanism.

Comment: Most of Kafka Streaming methods under pyspark are experimental. You need create a broker (like a session) and you it with your given functions. But I recommend you to jump Scala because most of Spark features are available and stable on Scala. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.kafka.utf8_decoder

Comment: But, how to do that in python? I'm using spark 1.6 in my cluster